# C: how to create a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, datagram

I am trying to create a socket for a client and server to communicate with.

I am not very familiar with how socket() and bind() works. How do I create a datagram socket?

When I try compiling it, it says the address of the socket will never be NULL and sockfd is not used.

```
int create_dg_socket(in_port_t port) {

    int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);

    int bind(int sockfd,
         const struct sockaddr *addr,
         socklen_t len);

    // Create the socket
    int sockfd;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if(socket==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "create_dg_socket not implemented!\n");
    exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your code producing an error?  Or ?

Comment: @devlincarnate yes

Comment: It's a typo: `if(socket==NULL)` should be `if(sockfd==NULL)`. And don't declare your own prototypes for standard functions like `socket` and `bind`. Include the correct header instead. `<sys/socket.h> in this case.

Comment: For learning C you might want to turn to something simpler than sockets.

Comment: @kaylum: ... and even `sockfd` would never be `NULL` as it's an `int` and not a pointer. For testing the successful outcome of the `socket()` call one wants to test against `-1`, which would indicate failure.

Comment: @alk Ah yes of course, good point. I didn't think clearly there.

Comment: @alk, what do you think NULL is? It is true that socket descriptor is **unlikely** to be NULL, but it nothing in BSD sockets protocol forbids this.

Comment: @Iona, if you are not very familiar with how `socket` and `bind` work the first thing to do is to get yourself familiar. There is no shortage of reading material on this topic, so I suggest you read it first. Otherwise you are destined to ask random questions, and you wan't even be able to understand the answer.

Comment: Sometime ago I was working in C socket programming I have some examples that could help you in my github repo https://github.com/koitoer/SSL-Sockets

Comment: @SergeyA: `NULL` is the defined to be a *pointer* value (typically `(void*)0`) which evaluates to `0` if used along with `==` operator. The call to create a socket returns an `int`, it is prototyped as `int socket(int, int, int)` and it returns `-1` on error, returning `0` is perfectly valid: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html

Comment: @alk, wrong. NULL is typically defined as `0L`. So yes, since `socket()` potentially can return 0 (though like I said **unlikely**, since 0 is STDIN, and, unless closed, is occupied) `sockfd` can be NULL.

Comment: @SergeyA: To leave aside for now how the C (not C++) Standard defined `NULL` I never said `socket()` cannot return `0`, all I said was `0` would not indicate an error, but `-1` did.

Comment: Regarding the definition of `NULL`: C11, 7.19/3 "*NULL [...]
which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant*" and 6.3.2.3/3: "*An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
void *, is called a null pointer constant.*"

Comment: @alk, you said this: *and even sockfd would never be NULL as it's an int and not a pointer*. This is just wrong, admit it and move on.

Comment: @alk, exactly. How do you understand *'An integer constant expression with the value 0'*? Just look at your implementation. It will have NULL defined as `0L`.

Comment: Please read to the end ... `(void*)0` simply isn't "*wrong*". I agree with your nitpicking on my inaccurate wording "*`socket()` would never return NULL*".

Comment: @alk, you said a very specific thing (which I already quoted). This thing is generally incorrect. That's it. Learn from mistake and move on. You thought NULL is usually (probably always, I am not a mind reader) defined as `(void*)0`. Common misconception, I see it all the time. I gave you a chance to learn something. Why insist on your mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I create a datagram socket?

Like this:

```
int create_dg_socket(in_port_t port) {

    // Create the socket

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "create_dg_socket cannot create socket! Error: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    // Bind the socket port

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "create_dg_socket cannot bind socket! Error: %d\n", errno);
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }

    return sockfd;
}
```

```
int sockfd = create_dg_socket(port);
if (sockfd == -1) {
    //...
    exit(-1);
}
```